# Me gustaría saber, si hay alguna forma de sumar los importes de varias tablas de acuerdo a las fechas con MySQL?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Me gustaría, saber si alguien me puede ayudar con este problema quiero sumar los importes de las tablas pero en donde las fechas coincidan por ejemplo teniendo las siguientes tablas.
[image]

El resultado debe salir así, ósea como la tabla repuesto tiene 2 fechas con 24//11/2021 sus importes se deben sumar haciendo un total de 50 para esta fecha ahora en la tabla flete encontramos igualmente 2 fechas con 24/11/2021 los importes de estas se suman teniendo un total de 20, en la tabla descuento solo hay 1 fecha 24/11/2021 por lo cual se queda con su importe de 5 y este importe resta a los demas y por ultimo la tabla MO tambien tiene importe de 5, ahora el resultado SQL que se debe mostrar es la suma de estos importes en esta fecha ósea :50 + 20 + 5 - 5 = 70 para la fecha 24/11/2021 y asi de la misma forma para los demas registros. Habra alguna manera de hacer este proceso con MySQL.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Si, es un join de las tablas sumadas.. intentaste algo?